# Pull right javascript success message in html modal

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have created a js function which flashes up a success message. My issue is it displays on the left and Im unsure of how to get it on the right, where I require it. I have tried pull-right as I would in a HTML file but im unsure how to implement it in JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/add/res/",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),

    success: function(response) {
        var successMessage = $('<div>').text('New Personnel file created in database').css('color', 'green');
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')
            $('#submitresource').html('Added!').addClass('btn-success')
            $('.modal-footer' ).append(successMessage);
            window.setTimeout(function() { 
            $('#addPersonnel').modal('hide'); }, 5000); location.reload(true);
            console.log("yers")              
        },
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json"
    })
```

Comment: Can you provide fiddle of the same ? People can not really create the environment to execute this.

Comment: not really, well not effectively at any rate, I'm pretty new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the pull-right class to your code as follows:

```
success: function(response) {
        var successMessage = $('<div>').text('New Personnel file created in database').css('color', 'green').addClass('pull-right');
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')
            $('#submitresource').html('Added!').addClass('btn-success')
            $('.modal-footer' ).append(successMessage);
            window.setTimeout(function() { 
            $('#addPersonnel').modal('hide'); }, 5000); location.reload(true);
            console.log("yers")              
        },
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json"
    })
```

And if you are not using bootstrap then you have to define the class properly

`.pull-right{float:right;}`